# Java - How would I make the execution until the thread finished?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java-threads

I'm new in the world of Java, and I started to use Thread, and there are some things that I can't understand.
My code is the follow:

```
    public void setSectionPage(String strSection) throws IOException{
         WebClient oWebClient = this._oWebClient;      
         // Create a new BotProcess to use Threads :D
         BotProcess bpBot = new BotProcess(){
             public void run(){
                 System.out.println("Loading: " + this.getURL());
                 try {
                    this.setoVictimWeb(oWebClient.getPage(this.getURL()));
                    System.out.println("1" + this.getoVictimWeb());
                 } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Bot.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Bot.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                 }
            }             
        }; 
        // Set the URL
        bpBot.setURL(this._strRootPage + strSection);
        // Start thread :D:D:D
        bpBot.start();
        // When the Thread finishes I'll get that VictimPage Object :D
        this._oVictimWeb = bpBot.getoVictimWeb();
        System.out.println("2" + bpBot.getoVictimWeb());
    }
```

> NOTE: I'm using HtmlUnit || The BotProcess's Class only extends Thread and implements some getters and setters.

Result in Console:

```
2null
Loading: www.google.com
1HtmlPage(www.google.com)@830191436
```

And it would must be like:

```
Loading: www.google.com
1HtmlPage(www.google.com)@830191436
2null
```

How would I make the execution until the thread finished?
And another thing, I work on several webpage, this means always the threads run in different places, would it be recommendable to use threadpool? Or what really is it?

Comment: use `thread.join();` to wait on thread finish

Comment: Just an advice: `setSectionPage()` does not imply that you start a new thread. This is considered bad design, as any new developper would not expect this side effect to occur.